# How to bind result on variable of another class?

Tags: php

I have a query like this:

```
if($stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM rol WHERE sug = ?"))
  {
        $stmt->bind_param("s", $role_slug);
        $stmt->bind_result($this->personal_model->sug);
        ...
```

I have imported in this file the class `Personal_model` that have `sug` variable declared like so:

```
private sug;
```

inside of the class. I should change the private as public or there is a better way to manipulate the variable of another class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add method for changing private property of class like:

```
class TEST
{

    private $sug;

    public function changeSlug($sug)
    {
        $this->sug = $sug;
    }
}
```

you can use it later like this

```
$personalModel = new TEST();
$newSug = 'new sug';
$personalModel->changeSlug($newSug);
```

Comment: but a private variable could be change in public or not for security?

Comment: IMO you should always have private properties in class. Change of state in object should be ALWAYS made by function. In this funciton you can validate  if given  variable is valid and only then change value of property and if not you can throw exception

Comment: so this is the best solution?

Comment: IMO yes. Object should validate data that haves. If you change property of a object somewhere else outside this object you don't have certainty that this data will be correct.